# Where does mysql_ssl_rsa_setup get OpenSSL files?

Tags: mysql, linux, ssl, openssl, debian

Getting "openssl not installed on this system" when running mysql_ssl_rsa_setup.

I installed openssl and mysql from source, both times keeping the default paths for installation (/usr/local/openssl for openssl [I actually renamed it to openssl from ssl to see if that was the problem], /usr/local/mysql for mysql).

The docs say it gets the path from the PATH environment variable, but there's no option to specify it in the command line. What is the default? How to change it? I have seen that you can modify /etc/environment to add PATH there, but the file is empty by default.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

According to [4.4.5 mysql_ssl_rsa_setup — Create SSL/RSA Files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-ssl-rsa-setup.html), `mysql_ssl_rsa_setup` uses the `openssl` command line tool:

> ***Note***
>
> mysql_ssl_rsa_setup uses the openssl command, so its use is contingent
>   on having OpenSSL installed on your machine.

---

> What is the default?

OpenSSL's default installation location is ***`/usr/local/ssl`***

---

> How to change it?

Use `--openssldir` when you configure the library. Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

---

You should ***not*** install OpenSSL in `/usr/bin` (and the libraries in `/usr/lib`). Its creates too many problems.

Instead, let the library install itself in `/usr/local/ssl`. Then you should be able to create a shell script located at `/usr/local/bin/openssl` that performs the following:

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/openssl
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl "$@"
```

Be sure to `chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/openssl`.

---

You can verify the OpenSSL tool being used with:

```
$ which openssl
/usr/local/bin/openssl
```

If needed, add `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
export PS1="\\h:\\W$ "
export UMASK=0022
export EDITOR=emacs

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin"
...
```